# Filtering a Dataframe based on another Dataframe in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df with columns

```
date: timestamp
status : String
name : String
```

I'm trying to find last status of the all the names

```
  val users = df.select("name").distinct
  val final_status = users.map( t =>
  {
     val _name =  t.getString(0)
     val record = df.where(col("name") === _name)
     val lastRecord = userRecord.sort(desc("date")).first
     lastRecord
   })
```

This works with an array, but with spark dataframe it is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**Update1 :** Using removeDuplicates

```
df.sort(desc("date")).removeDuplicates("name")
```

Is this a good solution?

Comment: a) This has been covered multiple times on so and it cannot work b) what is the source of removeDuplicates? Doesn't look like an existing method.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
df.sort(desc("date")).removeDuplicates("name")
```

is not guaranteed to work. The solutions in response to this question should work for you

[spark: How to do a dropDuplicates on a dataframe while keeping the highest timestamped row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623889/spark-how-to-do-a-dropduplicates-on-a-dataframe-while-keeping-the-highest-times/36624918#36624918)